# "Mouse Not Captured In Remote Desktop Sesion" in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd

I was used Disk2vhd to convert OS (Windows XP) into vhdx format and use Hyper-V Manager to run it as a virtual machine.

I had inserted integration services already and restart the VM, but "Mouse Not Captured In Remote Desktop Sesion" happened. The mouse cursor is there but cannot use the mouse, only can use keyboard.

I also tried manual insert integration services, but the result is "An error has occurred: One of the update processes returned error code 1603". I unchecked all the integration services (like data exchange, os shutdown) of the setting of the VM in Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: Not really, it's OS convert into virtual harddisk and want to run in virtual machine.

Comment: Then it's offtopic here. Post it on Super User instead.